# Java - javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: handshake alert: unrecognized_name - SNI is disabled

Tags: java, http, ssl, apache-commons, sni

Why I get that exception even when SNI is disabled? I'm completely sure it is:

```
logger.info("jsse.enableSNIExtension: " + System.getProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension"));
//do request
```

Prints "false".

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: handshake alert:  unrecognized_name
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: handshake alert:  unrecognized_name
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.handshakeAlert(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:506)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2114)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
        at .........
```

I get it when trying to do request to URL with self-signed certificate